# Displaying an image from resources in a datagrid that is bound to a list of objects

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid with a few columns.  One of the columns is templateColumn that I want to display an Image from my resources.  Here is the xaml:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="415" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,34,0,0" Name="dgLocalPlugins" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="806" SelectionMode="Single" AlternatingRowBackground="#CDEBEBEB">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Enabled" Binding="{Binding Path=Enabled}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" MinWidth="200" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Version" Binding="{Binding Path=Version}" />
        <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Wiki" Binding="{Binding Path=WikiUrl}" MaxWidth="100" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Author" Binding="{Binding Path=Author}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=Upgrade}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Here is the meat of the code behind that populates the list of objects the the datagrid is bound to:

```
foreach (string path in osapdFiles)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
    {
        PluginDescription desc = PluginHelper.Deserialize(path);
        desc.Upgrade = Properties.Resources.upgrade;
        desc.Status = "Stopped";
        desc.Enabled = false;
        pluginList.Add(desc);
    }
}

dgLocalPlugins.ItemsSource = pluginList;
```

When I debug and put a break point just after desc.Upgrade gets set I can see that there is something there, but the Image is not getting displayed in the datagrid.  What do I need to do to get the image to show up?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `PluginDescription` class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that the binding will update the UI when your properties are set.

Comment: I'm not sure that is the problem.  All the other columns are displayed properly.

Comment: Nope, I added that implementation to the PluginDescription class and it still doesn't show the image.

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` correctly for `Upgrade` property of `PluginDescription` class, I guess then the `Path` itself is not getting resolved then.

Put the path of the first `PluginDescription` into some image outside the datagrid.

i.e.

```
  <DataGrid Name="dgLocalPlugins" ... />
  <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=dgLocalPlugins, Path=ItemsSource[0].Upgrade}"/>
```

And check if this single image loads correctly. If it doesnt then I am sure the path is not getting resolved.